# CORS issues occurs randomly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am developing Web Api which passes data to mobile Application.My issue is Mobile Application facing CORS issue but randomly.Its working fyn sometimes.

I have already enabled cors by simply writing

[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] in all controllers as public

and 
 config.EnableCors();

in WebApiConfig.cs file

[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

The issue occurs sometime And I need permanant solution .
And May I know if the issue is on client side or serverside.

Help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have multiple endpoints or web applications exposed thru traffic manager or load balancer?

Comment: When it occurs, you need to check the HTTP status code of the response. Use the Network pane browser devtools to check. Because in those cases it’s most likely it’s a 4xx or 5xx error instead of a 200 OK success response. So you need to check the server logs on the server side to see what errors the server is logging, and when and why.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true };
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Add this to the WebApiConfig.cs file, you can remove the Cors attribute from the controllers. This should work.